# Dry wall, mounting 13KG whiteboard

Tags: drywall, mounting

So I just bought a 1800mm by 1200mm whiteboard for my study and what never occurred to me (stupidly enough) is how to mount this thing to a drywall.

It has obviously came with x8 raw plugs and x8 screws (2 each corner).

I am not sure how thick the drywall is, but the house is 20 years old and there is no holes anywhere (and 2 kids were brought up here).

What are my options here?

Comment: Do you know what the underlying framing is? Wood? Concrete?

Comment: Well there is a room on the other side of every wall (besides the window wall which has no room)so there is several inches of hollow before reaching another drywall. Obviously it has wooden support but can't really hear them when I knock and I don't have one of the devices to detect them.

Answer (score 1):

Drywall (Gypsum board) is not sufficient for hanging things (other than maybe very light picture frames), you'll want to attach the whiteboard to the underlying structure. How you do that, will depend on what the structure is.

Comment: Well, drywall is ok for hanging *some* things. And with numerous toggle style anchors (too many to be aesthetic or practical), a whiteboard *could* be held up, but I agree in general.

Comment: @bib I've edited a bit. Even though toggles and anchors exist, does not mean drywall should be used to support things.   Drywall is a finish material designed to hide the underlying structure, not a structural material (even though it may add rigidity to the wall).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't already have a stud finder, get one.  I consider them an essential tool to have in a house (like a hammer and screw drivers).  They also are pretty inexpensive as well, just don't get the cheapest in the hardware store but usually one model up from the cheapest is great for a home owner.

Ideally the corners of the board will line up with the studs on the wall and you can just mount straight to the studs.  This is ideal and will provide the strongest anchoring for the board.  Less than ideal would be using a drywall anchor but I consider it acceptable for this application.  I would throw away the anchors the gave you and purchase some with a high load strength at the hardware store.  My favorite are the ones that screw into the drywall.  I personally don't like toggle bolts since they don't really provide any more load strength and require a rather large hole and are cumbersome to work with.

Comment: Actually, toggle bolts (especially the newer strap types) spread the load over the surface area of the toggle, about 1/2 x 2, about 1 square inch. Screw in anchors (better than the tubular ones) rely on the crumbling strength of a very small surface area along the length of the hole in which they sit. I haven't seen test data on pullout forces, but I think the new toggles would win. +1 for pushing for a stud finder and stud mounting.

Comment: @bib - In the case of mounting a board against a wall you will have only very minimal pullout force.  The force will be near flush with the wall, directed to the floor, which is the best case scenario for screw in anchors load ratings.

Comment: Not a bad point, but I still don't like that tension force in drywall.

Answer (score 1):

A good white board that size costs hundreds of dollars. You can pick up a decent electronic stud finder for $10-20. Buying one to protect the investment in the whiteboard and to protect against it falling on someone's feet when in use is just the financially sound thing to do.

While there are a number of drywall anchors that can support that weight they are generally meant for static loads. A white board will have some live loads on it while in use. It may not be that much but why risk it when you can easily mount a board to the wall given how big it is.

Answer (score 0):

Whiteboard can not be attached on gypsum boards!You must fix it to the underlying structure,but even that im not sure is enough.Best would be to use UA structure (those are special kind of carriers used for gypsum board walls which are made of steel and they are used when you want to put a door on a dry wall or something like that).But since im guessing that you don't want to remove your boards and install additional structural elements,you should try to find where are (if there are any) horizontal structural elements and fix your board on them.Of course I'm presuming that your underlying structure is metal.If not you can try to locate vertical elements (I have no idea how to do it precicely since it is wood most likely, with metal you can use magnet) and then fix additional horizontal element for each of those.Usually, distance between vertical elements is 60 cm (sorry I'm from Europe).